# Targeting different templates in shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

```
{% if product.type  == 'Patio Furniture/Salsa Table' %}

<div id="dotted" style="height: auto;border-bottom:0px;text-align: center;" class="grid-uniform wrapper">
  <div class="grid__item large--one-whole">
<img alt="woman wearing colorful apron while working with bread doe in the kitchen" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1418/7648/files/BERLIN_Maud_Chalard_pour_Fermob_9.jpg?1296570615214079092">
    </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

I need to target two specialized templates called `product.no-variant` and `product.jacquard-tablecloths`.

This part should go here `{% if product.type  == 'Patio Furniture/Salsa Table' %}`

I'm pretty sure `product.type` is just the wrong suffix to use, I need the right one.

Comment: Why not set the template at the product level in product page in admin dashboard?

Comment: I did set the template that reason I'm having trouble targeting these templates is because they are special templates. product.no-variant and product-jacquard-tablecloths

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `product.template_suffix`

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-template_suffix

Shopify has a cheat sheet here that might help you out.

https://www.shopify.ca/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet

Comment: {% if product.template_suffix  == 'Patio Furniture/Salsa Table' %}
    <div id="dotted" style="height: auto;border-bottom:0px;text-align: center;" class="grid-uniform wrapper">
      <div class="grid__item large--one-whole">
    <img alt="woman wearing colorful apron while working with bread doe in the kitchen" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1418/7648/files/BERLIN_Maud_Chalard_pour_Fermob_9.jpg?1296570615214079092">
        </div>
 </div>
   
    {% endif %} This doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question? I thought you were trying to use the templates  `product.no-variant` and `product.jacquard-tablecloths` The template_suffix in that case would be `no-variant` and `jacquard-tablecloths`. Maybe you could explain a little more what you're trying to do? You can apply template to different product in your admin.

Comment: I am merely trying to add images to the specific product but because they are on a different template. This didn't work.  {% if product.template_suffix == 'jacquard-tablecloths' %}
    <div id="dotted" style="height: auto;border-bottom:0px;text-align: center;" class="grid-uniform wrapper">
      <div class="grid__item large--one-whole">
    <img alt="woman wearing colorful apron while working with bread doe in the kitchen" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1418/7648/files/BERLIN_Maud_Chalard_pour_Fermob_9.jpg?1296570615214079092">
        </div>
 </div>
    {% endif %}

Comment: Still not sure if I understand correctly? So you have two product templates and based on which one is chosen for a product you're looking to display a certain image?

Answer (score 1):

1)Are you sure this is actually the product type? You might try printing the product type to be sure.

`{{ product.type }}`

2) Can you use "contains" on the product description instead?

`{% if products.type contains 'Patio Furniture' OR products.type contains 'Salsa Table' %}`

3) Here are [all the product fields](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-type) - would tags be a better choice?

4) Remember you may have to downcase for certain field comparisons.

Comment: I want to keep this formula. I just need what to put instead of product.type in the code {% if product.type == 'product' %} for specialty templates called product.no-variant and product.jacquard-tablecloths

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is

```
{% if template contains 'jacquard-tablecloths' %}
  // Your code here
{% endif %}
```

Note: `{{ product.template_suffix }}` is only useful if you're just looking to print the name of the current template, which in your case would display "jacquard-tablecloths".